# Concatenating a list in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I have a windows console application that accepts a list of files as parameter each separated by a space, like `MyApp.exe 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt`. My folder has other file formats in addition to txt, but I am interested only in txt files. I would like to achieve something like this `MyApp.exe for %%i in (.\*.txt)`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only peculiarity is that you need to enable [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - do it like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%I IN (.\*.txt) DO SET files=!files! %%I
MyApp.exe !files!
```

This will call:

```
MyApp.exe .\1.txt .\2.txt .\3.txt
```

If you want to strip any path info, use `%%~nxI` instead of `%%I`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%I IN (.\*.txt) DO SET files=!files! %%~nxI
MyApp.exe !files!
```

This will result in:

```
MyApp.exe 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

Be aware that there is [a limit on the length of the command](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473):

> On computers running Microsoft Windows XP or later, the maximum length
>   of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 8191
>   characters.

Comment: Maybe `%%~fI` to get the filenames only as specified in the question?

Comment: @geisterfurz007: Valid point, maybe except for that would of course be `%%~nxI`

Comment: Erm yeah the German doc told that it would expand to the full filename so I got distracted, but you are right :)

Comment: @zb226: Thank you, you saved my time!